# open and close javascript window

Tags: javascript, html

I want to close a browser window whether it is in `open`. Am new for javascript so help me to create the below logic using javascript. My JavaScript code is here:

```
if (myWindow.open() == true) {
    myWindow.close();
} else {
    myWindow=window.open('http://index.html',
                         'popUpWindow',
                         'height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes'
                         );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `closed` property to check the window status, but first check whether the window object has been created or not.

```
var myWindow=null;
if (myWindow && !myWindow.closed) { //exist and is not closed
    myWindow.close();
    myWindow=null; //delete the object
} else { //not exist or is closed
    myWindow=window.open('http://index.html',
                         'popUpWindow',
                         'height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes'
                        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I agree with Christoph

```
if (!myWindow.closed) {
    myWindow.close();
}
```

further more

***Note: there is browser-specific differences with the above.*** If you opened the window with `Javascript (via window.open())` then you are allowed to close the window with javascript if you have reference in your case you have that. Firefox disallows you from closing other windows. I believe IE will ask the user for confirmation. Other browsers may vary.

Answer (score 0):

You are close to the right result.

Just check for

```
(myWindow.closed === false) // same as (!myWindow.closed)
```

instead of

```
(myWindow.open() == true)
```

(since `open()` will just open another window and your check will fail.)

Also note, that you need to write `index.html` or `http://sub.yourdomain.tld/index.html`, but not `http://index.html`.