# Is it possible to open a new window using location.href=""?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [open and close javascript window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540085/open-and-close-javascript-window)

Is it possible to open a new window using `location.href=""`? If so, how?

Comment: Do You really think you're the first one in the world needed that???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077770/window-location-href-and-window-open-methods-in-javascript

Comment: @user1856331, Maybe YOU thinks so, but you're not... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open a new browser window, use the window.open() method. For example, the following code opens this page in a new window.

```
myRef = window.open(''+self.location,'mywin',
'left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0');
```

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/openinga.htm

Comment: It opens as a pop up window in Chrome....

Answer (score 1):

No, setting the location of the window can only be used to load a new page in the same window.

To open a new window you use the `open` method with a target `_blank`:

```
window.open('http://www.guffa.com', '_blank');
```